# div size auto adjusting to content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a container div element using only HTML5/CSS3 which adjusts its size to its content according to the following rules:

1. if width of content > max-width an horizontal scroll bar will be shown
2. if height of content > max-height of container a vertical scroll bar will be shown
3. if content fits either horizontally or vertically that scroll bar will not be shown

So far I have this http://jsfiddle.net/Bikram/73e7atqm/ but can't get rid of horizontal scroll bar in chrome (in IE horizontal scroll bar isn't showing, as expected).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 5px;

    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;

    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}

.content {
    display: block;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    width : 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

I am aware that I can use JS/JQ to easily do this. My question is can it be achieved without them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/73e7atqm/4/

When you say `max-height` or `max-width`, the `div` won't grow beyond the specified dimensions.

Hence, you need to use the standard `width` or `height`.

Also, `overflow-y` is for `height` overflow only. Use `overflow` for both `height` and `width` overflows.